# DAX measure: disctinct count per group

Tags: dax, powerpivot, measure

Excel - Power Pivot

I am trying to create a measure to calculate a disctinct count (or a sum of a disctinct count) of a column - grouped by a second column.

Based on the column "lot" an the column "sku", I want to calculate the column "count_distinct_sku_by_lot". Column "sqm" is not relevant.

Which DAX code I could use?

[(picture of data added)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DORCr.png)

lot     sku sqm count_distinct_sku_by_lot 
lot1    sku1    1   1
lot2    sku2    2   2
lot2    sku2    3   2
lot2    sku3    4   2
lot3    sku4    5   3
lot3    sku4    6   3
lot3    sku5    7   3
lot3    sku5    8   3
lot3    sku6    9   3
lot4    sku7    11  1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated Column :

```
DistinctCount = 
VAR VrCurrentRow = [lot]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[sku]);
        FILTER(
            Sheet1;
            Sheet1[lot] = VrCurrentRow
        )
    )
```

Result :

[image]